# React-Native [ANDROID] Deeplinking "Open With" duplicates

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, deep-linking

### Description

I have described one deeplink intent for my app.

```xml
<manifest 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.company.appname"
>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
      <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:exported="true"
      >
        <!-- <scheme>://<host>:<port>[<path>|<pathPrefix>|<pathPattern>] -->
        <intent-filter>
          <!-- com.company.appname://logout-->
          <data
            android:scheme="com.company.appname"
            android:host="logout"
          />

          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

When I run

```sh
npx uri-scheme open com.company.appname://logout --android
```

i get this prompt which seems to be showing duplicates.
[image: Screenshot_1613643017]

### React Native version:

Run `react-native info` in your terminal and copy the results here.

```sh
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.6
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9980HK CPU @ 2.40GHz
    Memory: 4.25 GB / 32.00 GB
    Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.0. - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.3, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29
      Build Tools: 29.0.3
      System Images: android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
    Xcode: 12.3/12C33 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 1.8.0_282 - /usr/bin/javac
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: ^17.0.1 => 17.0.1 
    react-native: 0.63.2 => 0.63.2 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

### Steps To Reproduce

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

1. Configure AndroidManifest the same as mine
2. run `npx uri-scheme open com.company.appname://logout --android`

### Expected Results

I expect to be able to see one option on the "Open with" prompt.

Answer (score 1):

So what happened to me was that my `<data android:scheme` referenced the full package path instead of the "shorthand" scheme - which came from my expo's app.json and the android build.

So I made sure that my `src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` in the main `manifest` tag has a `package="com.fullpackagepath.specific_appname"` tag and then my scheme tag references the scheme only: `<data android:scheme="specific_appname" />`.

Also, my expo's `app.json`:

```
{
  "expo": {
    name: "specific_appname",
    slug: "specific_appname", 
    ...
    scheme: "specific_appname",
    ...
    android: {
      package: "com.fullpackagepath.specific_appname"
    ...
    }
...
```

Not saying this is a 100% the way things should be done, just how I resolved the duplicate "open with" window

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was experiencing was to do with a third party library overwriting my intents

The library was https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth

In my case, Switching out the `manifestPlaceholders` logic shown [here](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth#android-setup)
for a hardcoded `intent` in the AndroidManifest XML worked a treat. (https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-android#capturing-the-authorization-redirect).

e.g

```xml
<manifest ...
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
  ...
  <activity
        android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
        tools:node="replace">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="com.example.app"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  ...
</manifest>
```